# Is there a way to create a spectrogram of an audio file using Swift and AudioKit?

Tags: swift, appkit, audiokit, spectrogram

I am trying to create a spectrogram, like the one in the image, from an audio file using Swift for a macOS app.  I am using AppKit but could implement SwiftUI as well.  I cam across audio kit and it seems like the perfect library to use for this type of thing, but I have not been able to find any examples of what I am looking for in an of the audio kit repositories, audio kit UI nor the cookbook.  Is this something that is possible with audio kit?  If so, can anyone help me with this?
Thanks so much!

I have previously tried using [apple's example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/visualizing_sound_as_an_audio_spectrogram) and changed the code in the AudioSpectrogram + AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate file.  The original code is as follows:

```
extension AudioSpectrogram: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                          didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                          from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList()
    var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        sampleBuffer,
        bufferListSizeNeededOut: nil,
        bufferListOut: &audioBufferList,
        bufferListSize: MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: audioBufferList),
        blockBufferAllocator: nil,
        blockBufferMemoryAllocator: nil,
        flags: kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
        blockBufferOut: &blockBuffer)
    
    guard let data = audioBufferList.mBuffers.mData else {
        return
    }

    /// The _Nyquist frequency_ is the highest frequency that a sampled system can properly
    /// reproduce and is half the sampling rate of such a system. Although  this app doesn't use
    /// `nyquistFrequency` you may find this code useful to add an overlay to the user interface.
    if nyquistFrequency == nil {
        let duration = Float(CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer).value)
        let timescale = Float(CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer).timescale)
        let numsamples = Float(CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer))
        nyquistFrequency = 0.5 / (duration / timescale / numsamples)
    }

    if self.rawAudioData.count < AudioSpectrogram.sampleCount * 2 {
        let actualSampleCount = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer)
        
        let ptr = data.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: actualSampleCount)
        let buf = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: actualSampleCount)
        
        rawAudioData.append(contentsOf: Array(buf))
    }

    while self.rawAudioData.count >= AudioSpectrogram.sampleCount {
        let dataToProcess = Array(self.rawAudioData[0 ..< AudioSpectrogram.sampleCount])
        self.rawAudioData.removeFirst(AudioSpectrogram.hopCount)
        self.processData(values: dataToProcess)
    }
 
    createAudioSpectrogram()
}

func configureCaptureSession() {
    // Also note that:
    //
    // When running in iOS, you must add a "Privacy - Microphone Usage
    // Description" entry.
    //
    // When running in macOS, you must add a "Privacy - Microphone Usage
    // Description" entry to `Info.plist`, and check "audio input" and
    // "camera access" under the "Resource Access" category of "Hardened
    // Runtime".
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) {
        case .authorized:
                break
        case .notDetermined:
            sessionQueue.suspend()
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio,
                                          completionHandler: { granted in
                if !granted {
                    fatalError("App requires microphone access.")
                } else {
                    self.configureCaptureSession()
                    self.sessionQueue.resume()
                }
            })
            return
        default:
            // Users can add authorization in "Settings > Privacy > Microphone"
            // on an iOS device, or "System Preferences > Security & Privacy >
            // Microphone" on a macOS device.
            fatalError("App requires microphone access.")
    }
    
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    
    #if os(macOS)
    // Note than in macOS, you can change the sample rate, for example to
    // `AVSampleRateKey: 22050`. This reduces the Nyquist frequency and
    // increases the resolution at lower frequencies.
    audioOutput.audioSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1]
    #endif
    
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)
    } else {
        fatalError("Can't add `audioOutput`.")
    }
    
    guard
        let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInMicrophone,
                                                 for: .audio,
                                                 position: .unspecified),
        let microphoneInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone) else {
            fatalError("Can't create microphone.")
    }
    
    if captureSession.canAddInput(microphoneInput) {
        captureSession.addInput(microphoneInput)
    }
    
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}

/// Starts the audio spectrogram.
func startRunning() {
    sessionQueue.async {
        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) == .authorized {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}
```

}

I got rid of the configureCaptureSession function and replaced the rest of the code to get the following code:

```
public func captureBuffer() {
    
    var samplesArray:[Int16] = []
    
    let asset = AVAsset(url: audioFileUrl)

    
    let reader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: asset)

    let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]

        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatLinearPCM
        ]

        let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track, outputSettings: settings)
        reader.add(readerOutput)
        reader.startReading()


    while let buffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {

       var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1, mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil))
       var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?

       CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        buffer,
        bufferListSizeNeededOut: nil,
        bufferListOut: &audioBufferList,
        bufferListSize:  MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size,
        blockBufferAllocator: nil,
        blockBufferMemoryAllocator: nil,
        flags: kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
        blockBufferOut: &blockBuffer
       );
    
        let buffers = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &audioBufferList.mBuffers, count: Int(audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers))
        
        for buffer in buffers {

            let samplesCount = Int(buffer.mDataByteSize) / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
            let samplesPointer = audioBufferList.mBuffers.mData!.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: samplesCount)
            let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: samplesPointer, count: samplesCount)
            
            
            for sample in samples {

                //do something with you sample (which is Int16 amplitude value)
                samplesArray.append(sample)

            }
        }
        guard let data = audioBufferList.mBuffers.mData else {
            return
        }

        /// The _Nyquist frequency_ is the highest frequency that a sampled system can properly
        /// reproduce and is half the sampling rate of such a system. Although  this app doesn't use
        /// `nyquistFrequency` you may find this code useful to add an overlay to the user interface.
        if nyquistFrequency == nil {
            let duration = Float(CMSampleBufferGetDuration(buffer).value)
            let timescale = Float(CMSampleBufferGetDuration(buffer).timescale)
            let numsamples = Float(CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(buffer))
            nyquistFrequency = 0.5 / (duration / timescale / numsamples)
        }

        if self.rawAudioData.count < AudioSpectrogram.sampleCount * 2 {
            let actualSampleCount = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(buffer)
            
            let ptr = data.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: actualSampleCount)
            let buf = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: actualSampleCount)
            
            rawAudioData.append(contentsOf: Array(buf))
        }

        while self.rawAudioData.count >= AudioSpectrogram.sampleCount {
            let dataToProcess = Array(self.rawAudioData[0 ..< AudioSpectrogram.sampleCount])
            self.rawAudioData.removeFirst(AudioSpectrogram.hopCount)
            self.processData(values: dataToProcess)
        }
     
        createAudioSpectrogram()
    }
}
```

In AudioSpectrogram: CALayer file, I changed the original lines 10-30 from

```
public class AudioSpectrogram: CALayer {

// MARK: Initialization

override init() {
    super.init()
    
    contentsGravity = .resize
    
    configureCaptureSession()
    audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self,
                                        queue: captureQueue)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override public init(layer: Any) {
    super.init(layer: layer)
}
```

to the following:

```
public class AudioSpectrogram: CALayer {

@objc var audioFileUrl: URL
// MARK: Initialization

override init() {
    self.audioFileUrl = selectedTrackUrl!
    super.init()
    
    
    contentsGravity = .resize
    captureBuffer()
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override public init(layer: Any) {
    self.audioFileUrl = selectedTrackUrl!
    super.init(layer: layer)
}
```

The changed code allows me to specify the audio file to use when the Spectrogram is called from another area in my app.

The following is an example of what I am trying to achieve.  It was done using FFMPEG.
[Example Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUo3W.jpg)

This is the output I get from my code:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRHnP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a Spectrogram in the AudioKitUI Swift package: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKitUI/blob/main/Sources/AudioKitUI/Visualizations/SpectrogramView.swift

You would need to pass it an AudioKit Node but it should be interchangeable with the other visualizers in the Cookbook.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Nick C. I have come across that Spectrogram before, but it is different than what I am looking for.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AudioKit is not the tool you want for this. You want AVFoundation. Apple has [an example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/visualizing_sound_as_an_audio_spectrogram) of exactly what you're describing.

The tool at the heart of this is a DCT (discrete cosine transform) to convert windows of samples into a collection of component frequencies you can visualize. AVFoundation is the tool you use to turn your audio file or live recording into a buffer of audio samples so you can apply the DCT.

Comment: Thanks for the response @RobNapier.  I have tried using that example project in the past.  I edited my question to include the code I tried using.  What would you do differently?  Thanks!

Comment: In what way did it "not work correctly?" What are the changes you made (this is a lot of code to try to mentally "diff" from the original), and why did you make changes? (Did the code work before you made changes? Why did you need to change anything?) In what mathematical way is  the image you want to produce different than the image this does produce?

Comment: Thanks again @RobNapier.  I have made the changes you requested.  Hopefully it is a bit clearer now

Comment: This is probably too large of a debugging job for Stack Overflow. It's not well designed for "here is a ton of code; what's wrong with it?" However, I am suspicious of your AVAssetReaderTrackOutput settings. You didn't set the bit depth, float/fixed config, or number of channels. You just said "LPCM." I don't know what the defaults are for that (my guess would be 32-bit float, maybe with the same number of channels as the input, deinterleaved, but that's just a guess, but the point is it's not the same thing as the sample code).